# Vertical text alignment in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

In the Crystal Reports editor that comes with Visual Studio (2008) is it possible to align text to the center of a text box rather than to the top?

I can't find the option anywhere and a Google search is not encouraging but I just can't bring myself to believe that they would not include such an obvious feature.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no vertical alignment for crystal reports that I could find.  A potential work-around is programming line breaks.

Comment: Not for centered text it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find an option to vertically align text within a label, but you can vertically align labels within a section. Use the horizontal guidelines on the left margin to adjust the alignment. You may need to right-click the guideline and un-check "Snap to Grid" to get more precise positioning.

[image: horizontal guideline]

Comment: Which triangle tabs? This seems like a valid solution to my case

Comment: Excellent Solution
It works like cream!
By unchecking Snap to Grid, I was able to move & align my labels precisely

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with strings, as you will see a *paragraph* tab instead of a *number* tab when you enter the **FORMAT FIELD** menu.  To make your number a string you should format it as a formula field thusly:

```
chr(13) + chr(10) + totext(mynumber,0)
```

Then in the **FORMAT FIELD** menu select - Line spacing: ***multiple*** of: **0.2**

You may need to *experiment with the 0.2 value* until you find your number (i.e. string prefixed with a carriage return) nicely centered in the middle of your box.

Cheers,
Chilly

Comment: It doesn't need to be a formula, just drop your field into a text label, and put a carriage return out the front of it with Ctrl + Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment with programming line breaks. Algorithm for the one cell:

1. Count the number of characters in data (`iTextLen`).
2. Find the number of text lines in cell (`iLineNum`). Calculated empirically.
3. Find the row length in characters (`iLineLen`). Calculated empirically.
4. Calculate count the number of halfbreaks by formula `(iLineNum — 1) — (iTextLen / iLineLen)`.

   `@formula` in crystal syntax:

   ```
   Local NumberVar iLineNum:= 5;
   Local NumberVar iLineLen:= 30;
   Local NumberVar iTextLen:= Length({DataSource});

   Local StringVar sRet:= '';
   Local NumberVar i;
   Local NumberVar iLinesNum:= Truncate(iLineNum - 1) - Truncate(iTextLen / iLineLen); 
   For i:= 1 to iLinesNum Do ( sRet:= sRet + chr(13) );

   sRet
   ```
5. Add formula to the top and bottom of data. Text objects will look like this:
   `{@formula}{DataSource}{@formula}`

   Font size of `@formula` must be halved of font size `{DataSource}`. For example, if the font size of `{DataSource}` equal to 20, the `@formula` should be equal to 10:
   [image: formula-position-and-font-size]

Algorithm works better with monospaced typeface, but with proportional typeface works in most cases.

Algorithm for multiple cells is differ only that `iLineNum` will be the maximum number of characters in data of all cells.

Comment: Working fine change iLineNum, iLineLen value for need basis

Answer (score -3):

in crystal report 10   the label >> right click >> format Text >> Common >> text rotation . choose 90 degree the text will have a vertical alignment
same in a field or any object you add to the report 
hope that i help you

note the answer (Format text > tab Paragraph, Horizontal alignment: Centered) is a wrong

Comment: This is not what vertical alignment means bilal.  Vertical alignment means that if I have a box that is 50 units high, and text that is 10 units high, then there will be 20 units of space above the text and 20 units of space below the text. It is a basic feature in any layout system I can think of.

Comment: Talk about unnecessary levels of punishment for misunderstanding the question. I upvoted because I searched for the wrong thing, and found the answer regardless.

Comment: +1 You're right VoronoiPotato. Incorrect but useful answer. Thanks bilal :)