# Vertical align in Crystal Report Control

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am very new to Crystal Report.

I have searched everywhere how to align a crystal report object vertically(Example: top , Middle, Bottom) but could not find an answer.

I found that I can set Horizontal Alignment setting by using 「horAlignment」 property.

But I can't set  Vertical Alignment Setting.

How could I do to set vertical text align.

With Regards.

Comment: Vertical alignment possible with programming line breaks:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35111657/5775332

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for a way to do this for quite awhile. This [forum post](http://scn.sap.com/thread/992159) is the closest thing to an answer I've been able to find. It doesn't seem to be supported directly by Crystal Reports.