# Formatting the layout of data in a cell, Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to format the output of my data in crystal reports 2008. Currently, you can see in the picture that the data is in the top left of the cell. I am trying to have the data appear on the bottom left hand spacing of the cell, instead of top left hand side, for gldesc. Is there a way to do this?
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456150/vertical-text-alignment-in-crystal-reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after examining the problem further, I realized that I was making this too hard, and all you have to do is drag and drop, to place the formulas/items where you would like them to be.

I was going to delete this question but I decided to answer it and share how I fixed it incase someone else has this question along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Formula with that field, by calling that data field in that formula. Then in the section place a text object and place the forumla where you wish in that text object. Hope this helps.